# LC3 Help - not printing the amount I want to print

Tags: assembly, lc3, lc3-trap

I am doing a project that follows as:

You will edit the program you wrote for Lab #9 that prompts the user for the value of the number of bits to rotate (AMOUNT) a given value (ORIGINAL), and stores the rotated (ROTATED) value.

For this lab exercise, you will need to display on the console, the values of ORIGINAL and ROTATED bits as 16-character strings with correct labels.

Example: If ORIGINAL contains the bit pattern 1111000000001111 and the user entered a 5 as the amount to be rotated, then your program should display the following output:

AMOUNT: 5

ORIGINAL:    1111000000001111

ROTATED:     0000000111111110

MY code is as follows:

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R0 PROMPT         ; loads R0 with the starting address of prompt
PUTS                  ; prints prompt
LD R0 ENDLINE
OUT
GETC
OUT
ADD R4 R0 #0
ADD R4 R4 #-16
ADD R4 R4 #-16
ADD R4 R4 #-16
GETC
OUT
ADD R5 R0 #0
ADD R5 R5 #0
ADD R5 R5 #-16
ADD R5 R5 #-16
ADD R5 R5 #-16
ADD R4 R4 #0
BRz zloop
ADD R5 R5 #10
zloop
ST R5 AMOUNT
ST R6 AMOUNT
LD R2, MASK           ; MASK = 1000 0000 0000 0000 for checking MSB
LD R0, ORIGINAL       ; ORIGINAL = xF00F
loop2
AND R3, R2, R0        ; checks to see if MSB is 0 or 1(negative)
BRn loop              ; ignores next code if negative (i.e. MSB = 1)
ADD R0, R0, R0        ; Left Shift
ADD R5, R5, #-1       ; AMOUNT--
ADD R6, R6 #1
BRp loop2             ; if still positive, repeat check from above
BRz loop3             ; if negative, we're done! so jumps to store final ORIGINAL value
loop                  ; comes here after checking if MSB is 1 
ADD R0, R0, R0        ; left shift
ADD R0, R0, #1        ; add 1 to rotate 
ADD R5, R5, #-1       ; decrement amount
ADD R6, R6 #1
BRp loop2             ; if positive, we still have work to do. jumps up to loop2 to go through check again
loop3                 ; we will arrive here if ORIGINAL value is positive and AMOUNT is 0
LD R0 ENDLINE
OUT
LEA R0, AMOUNTSTR
PUTS
ADD R0 R6 #0
HALT
OUT

LD R0 ENDLINE
ST R0, ROTATED        ; stores original into ROTATED



ENDLINE .FILL x000A     
AMOUNT .FILL x001E
ROTATED .BLKW #1
ORIGINAL .FILL xF00F
ORIGSTR .STRINGZ "ORIGINAL: 1111000000001111"
AMOUNTSTR .STRINGZ "AMOUNT: "
MASK .FILL x8000
PROMPT .STRINGZ "Enter a two digit number to rotate a binary string up to 16 bits. Example: 05"

.END
```

When I run it and enter in the digits, I either get a square with a question mark in it or a an ASCII code that is not what I need.  I tried to see if I had to add the corresponding ASCII value difference to get the character I was looking for, and that's when I kept getting the blocked question mark.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This website is not a debugging service.  Single step your code and if any one instruction doesn't do what it should then that's where to look.

Comment: If you're having a problem just with printing, then replace the above code with a minimal reproducible code that has illustrates that issue.